# Trouble understanding a strange Python import

Tags: python

I made this littlet test set up:

```
test\
    config.py
    run.py
    movie\
        __init__.py
        ironman.py
        impossible.py
```

I ran `run.py` from the `test` folder.

**run.py**:

```
import movie.ironman
```

**ironman.py**:

```
import impossible #okay
import config     #okay
```

What crazy is that both of those imports are good. Assuming that my path is relative to the `test` folder. I can understand how `config.py` was imported, however, how is `impossible.py` imported? Shouldn't it be `movie.impossible` instead?

I'm really bothered this and the import system in python is a bit confusing to me. It would be great if anyone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? The behavior of imports changed between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Blckknght: I imagine Python 2.  I tested this on 2.7 and it works (all imports succeed).

Comment: I used python2.7. Could this be it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Till Python 2.5 there was no real differentiation between relativ and absolute imports. Relative imports are relative to the current module, in your example `movie`.
In newer python versions you can/have to import relative modules with a leading `.`:

```
import config
from .impossible import something
```

Here `impossible` is a module relative to the movie directory. And `config` is absolute to the search path, which also contains the directory of the calling program `run.py`.

Comment: Hm, leading with `.` is cool. In my example, if import is relative to my `movie` folder, than `import impossible` would make sense but `import config` wouldn't because config is a level up. Right?

Comment: If your script starts with "from \_\_future\_\_ import absolute_import", your code behaves the Python 3 way and not using a . will give an exception. Recommended.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE! Stuff finally make sense XD Guess the change from Python2 to Python3 wouldn't be so bad afterall

Comment: Note that  you can use `.` by itself to indicate the current package. So, `ironman.py` can import `impossible.py` with `from . import impossible`.